# Handsontable with datetimepicker

Tags: datetimepicker, handsontable

Is there a plugin to implement datetimepicker in handsontable? The closest I got was pickadate fork [here](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/tree/gh-pages) but I have no clue how to implement this in Handsontable.

Comment: have you tried using the `date` type?

Comment: yes. it implements date picker but I also want to select time along with date.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by modifying the file `handsontable.full.js`. 
Take this file: http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js

Find the section "Pikaday":

```
/*!
 * Pikaday
 *
 * Copyright Â© 2014 David Bushell | BSD & MIT license | https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday
 */

(function (root, factory)
{

.......

    return Pikaday;

}));
```

Replace it with this fork: https://github.com/owenmead/Pikaday/blob/master/pikaday.js

Then specify the date format like: `dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to customize existing date editors for HT.
But sad thing pikaday.js doesn't support time selection (check section time picker https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday). You have to create custom dp for HT.
https://handsontable.com/docs/8.1.0/tutorial-cell-editor.html

Take a look at

```
class CalendarEditor extends TextEditor
```

Or you can extend from

```
Handsontable.editors.DateEditor
```

Choose any date picker with time picker.